# How do I force Windows 7 backup to include a drive in the scheduled backup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I'm trying to use Windows 7's backup and restore utility to schedule the creation of a system image of 3 partitions (C:, D: and E: drives).

When I configure the backup utility, I choose the option that allows me to control what to backup, uncheck all the 'Data Files' and 'Computer' options, and check the option that says 'Include a system image of drives:...'; but the D: drive is not listed there (and it's not backed up).

Is there any way to force Windows to include the D: drive in the System image created during backup?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Please re-read it, and correct any grammatical mistakes you might have.

Comment: As far as I know Windows System Image backup does not allow for you to exclude files, you must be using File and Folder backup?

Comment: If you don't select any files to do backup, but select to include a system image, the backup creates a system image, my problem is that is leaving a partition out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After various unsuccessful attempts at solving the problem, I stumbled upon the solution while looking at a Microsoft forum (sorry, don't remember the URL).

It appears that the criteria that's used for marking a drive as Critical, and therefore marking it for backup when asking for a scheduled system image, includes the presence of a Service with files in the given drive.

So it is possible to force windows backup to create a system image of drive by issuing this command:

```
set drive=D
sc create DummySvc%drive% binPath= %drive%:\Dummy.exe start= disabled DisplayName= "Dummy For Backup (%drive%:)"
```

Which creates a dummy service that's disabled, but refers to a file in the target drive. This will force Windows Backup to include it, solving my original problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup multiple partitions, you'll need to choose the drives under computer on top of "include a system image."

**edit**

Looks like you have to hit up the command line to image data volumes.

Use the following command.

> wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:*targetpath* -include:c:,d:,e: -quiet

Add that to Task Scheduler and you should be good to go.

**note**

Windows does not do multiple image versions on network shares (no clue why). An easy solution is to just create a batchfile that cycles through *n* directories for you backups. You would have to setup the directories first.

> @echo off
>
> set backupdir = *path to backup directories*
>
> for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in ('dir "%backupdir%" /b /ad /o-d`) do (wbadmin start >backup -backuptarget:"%%~fI" -include:c:,d:,e: -quiet)

You could also create *n* tasks in Task Scheduler and have them run *daily*. Then change the *daily* setting from every **1** day to *n* days. That's probably a more complicated way.

Comment: That option exists but only works if I do it manually. I want my scheduled backup to include the D: partition that is left out.

Comment: Ahh, true. Didn't realize the scheduled backup does not include imaging data partitions. You'll have to hit up the command line. I'll edit my answer.